# Understanding lincom confidence intervals (STATA)

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval

I'm trying to understand confidence intervals for linear combinations of parameters (lincom command in STATA). Let's say I'm interested in whether smoking is associated with low birth weight (using the lbw dataset, see example in help logit).

```
webuse lbw
logit low age lwt i.race smoke ptl ht ui

age     -.0271003   .0364504    -0.74   0.457   -.0985418   .0443412
lwt     -.0151508   .0069259    -2.19   0.029   -.0287253   -.0015763

race    
black   1.262647    .5264101    2.40    0.016   .2309024    2.294392
other   .8620792    .4391532    1.96    0.050   .0013548    1.722804

smoke   .9233448    .4008266    2.30    0.021   .137739     1.708951
ptl     .5418366    .346249     1.56    0.118   -.136799    1.220472
ht      1.832518    .6916292    2.65    0.008   .4769494    3.188086
ui      .7585135    .4593768    1.65    0.099   -.1418484   1.658875
_cons   .4612239    1.20459     0.38    0.702   -1.899729   2.822176
```

As I understand, the logit for a non-smoker is .46, which has a 95% confidence interval of -1.9 ; 2.82 (_cons). The additional effect for being a smoker is .92, which has a 95% confidence interval of .14 ; 1.71 (smoke), and this effect is significant at the 95% level (p = .021).

I want to calculate the logit and confidence interval of low birth weight for: 1) non-smokers 2) smokers, so I turn to the lincom command.

```
lincom _cons (redundant as this is the _cons coefficient)
(   1)  [low]_cons  =   0
.4612239    1.20459     0.38    0.702   -1.899729   2.822176
lincom _cons+smoke
[low]smoke  +   [low]_cons  =   0
1.384569    1.155967    1.20    0.231   -.8810857   3.650223
```

The 95% confidence interval for smokers overlaps with that of non-smokers, even though the 95% confidence interval for the additional effect of smoking !=0 with 95% confidence. I'm finding it difficult to understand why this is, surely the linear combined estimate for smokers should not overlap with the constant?

Comment: It has to do with the uncertainty estimated in the intercept/constant. This value is unknown, but per the model *should be* the same for both smokers and non-smokers.

Comment: @Andy W Can you provide some guidance on interpretation? i.e. is it correct to say that smoking is associated with higher odds of low birth weight, but the odds of smokers and non-smokers are not significantly different at the 95% level?